# Print elements from an array member of a structure in C

Tags: c

I have been solving a problem of CyclicRotation. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Results{
  int *A;
  int N;
};

struct Results solution(int A[], int N, int K){
  struct Results result;
  int *tab, i=0, j=0;
  tab = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
  if(N==0){
    result.A = A;
    result.N = N;
    return result;
  }
  if(K>N){
    K = K % N;
  }
  if(K<N && N != 0){
    for(i=N-K;i<N;i++){
      tab[j] = A[i];
      j = j + 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i<N-K){
      tab[j] = A[i];
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  } else {
    tab = A;
  }
  result.A = tab;
  result.N = N;
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  int j[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  int mylen;
  int myk = 3;
  mylen = sizeof(j)/sizeof(j[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this in the code:

```
int main()
{
  int j[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  int mylen;
  int myk = 3;
  mylen = sizeof(j)/sizeof(j[0]);
  printf("The result is %d",solution(j,mylen,myk).A);
  return 0;
}
```

The expected result is 6782345, but the result in the console is different:

```
The result is -591373584
```

I'm not sure if the array printing is correct (given that is an array, perhaps I need a loop?). Please, could you give me a help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if(N==0){` you invoked *Implementation Defined Behavior* with `malloc(N*sizeof(int));` so the rest may behave differently on different compiles. [C11 Standard -  7.22.3 Memory management functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3) Also `solution()` is never called by your program?? But assuming it as as you write, you would simply loop, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < mylen; i++) /* output result.A[i] */`

Comment: Hello @DavidC.Rankin, the document you mention made me rethink if I am doing something wrong... if N is 0, then there is no need to call malloc I guess. About your second question that is my headache, I don't know if I have to loop to return each element of the array... let me edit my question to be clearer. Thank you.

Comment: If you pass the array, you can update all elements in your function and the changes will be visible back in the caller. Passing the array (actually a pointer to the first element of the array) provide the memory address to the function for the start of the array. You can operate on the elements in the function and any changes will be reflected back in the original array in `main()`

Comment: I really appreciate it when the answer makes me investigate more, you are right @DavidC.Rankin about memory-allocation functions when the number of bytes requested is 0... behavior could be weird in C. About what you mention of arrays, it means that I can call it back and print each element, isn't it? Thank you very much for your time and answer!

Comment: Yes, after `solutions()` returns, you can then print the update array values out from `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  int j[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  int mylen;
  int myk = 3;
  mylen = sizeof(j)/sizeof(j[0]);
    struct Results results = solution(j, mylen, myk);
    for(int i = 0; i < mylen; i++)
        printf("%d\n", results.A[i]);
    free(results.A);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Xenox Inno, just a question, shouldn't I free `results.B` too? or when I invoke `free(results.A)` then all the struct is free?

Comment: free() is to use with dynamic allocated memory, which is memory allocated by malloc(). You don't really need to call free() when you going to quit the program, just a good practivce.

Comment: When I tried `free(results)` I received an alert telling me `Struct results to parameter of incompatible type void *`, then I should free by member, not by struct, am I right?

Comment: You should only free the address return by malloc or calloc. If realloc used, then just free the address return from realloc. Such function might return NULL if operation fail.